# Should I tell potential new employer about counter offer?

Tags: job-offer, career-development, new-job

I was offered a new job(was not looking) then received a counter offer from my current job. I do enjoy my current job to some extent.

Should I tell my potential new employer about the counter offer or will that just annoy them? I'm leaning towards moving as it will potentially help my career.

Comment: How did your current employer know you got an offer? You're playing a dangerous game if you're trying to auction yourself.

Comment: I told my current employer I've been given a job offer

Comment: Relevant reading - [When does accepting an offer to stay with my current firm make sense?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/54748/when-does-accepting-an-offer-to-stay-with-my-current-firm-make-sense)

Comment: @davey Why would you tell them? Where you actually hoping they'd give you a counter-offer?  // What is your actual question here? We can't tell you how to plan your career path, we can only give general tips on how to make a particular decision. Check the related questions on counter offers listed on the right.

Comment: @Lilienthal to get more money of course, it would make the decision that more easier. When both places have equal pros and cons, then money is probably the only deciding factor left.

Comment: That's typically done by asking for a raise, not threatening to leave. Check the related questions and the search, we have plenty of general questions on the value and otherwise of counter offers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, unless you wish to use your counter-offer to negotiate the original offer up.

Keep in mind that knowing that they have a *competitor* (even if it is your current company) does not really help them.

Comment: I was thinking that although I've negotiated higher salary in the past when given an offer.