# Will my current Place of Employment (A) Contact Potential Place of Employment (B) for counter-offer proof?

Tags: job-offer, negotiation

I currently worked for **Company A**, but I had an interview with **Company B** and they've offered me more money than Company A.

**Company A** would like to keep me, so they're matching what **Company B** has offered, but they want proof of my offer from Company A.

I would rather keep my offer details personal.

> **Would Company A call Company B to get proof of the job offer?**

Comment: Related - [When does accepting an offer to stay with my current firm make sense?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/54748/when-does-accepting-an-offer-to-stay-with-my-current-firm-make-sense)

Comment: If you decided to take the counter-offer, is there a reason you don't want to share the job offer?

Comment: Surely you received a written offer from Company B? If not, ask for one. But before that I would give serious thought to whether you really want to accept a counter offer.

Answer (score 11):

No, they wouldn't.
And even on the remotest of possibilities they did, Company B would tell them to get lost.

If company A is so unfamiliar with the value of what you do that they don't believe you could possibly get the offer you've got, then that's just another reason you don't want to continue working there.

Comment: In the US that information would probably be considered confidential. Even if it weren't, no, I'm not sharing my company's compensation structure with an outside party, especially one that's competing with us over a job candidate.