# Going back to an old company within 2 months of starting new job

Tags: resume, job-change, resignation

I joined my previous company in Jan 2013 and quit by Sep 2017 only because my boss wasn’t great and team change options were taking so long to work out.

Meanwhile, I got an offer on LinkedIn from a competitor which I had ignored. But since the team hangs was taking so long and I felt I wasn’t doing justice to my team to simply wait for things to work out I quit. I eventually joined the competitor.

Now, I miss my old company so much and my heart goes out to it. It’s just been 2 months in this new job, and I kind of got another offer from my previous company which seems interesting.

The current company is undergoing some leadership transition and it sucks. I am not happy with the boss here either (they are temporary, I hear) it feels weird. Super confused as to what to do.

Would this look bad on my resume?  what would you do if you were in my shoes?

Edit 2: ok I deleted the whole of my 1st edit. I’ve decided to take my old organisation’s offer for the new role. Now my question is what should I tell  the current employer? Reason to quit. What would yours be? Should I just tell them going back to my old company? I would prefer to be true as that doesn’t stress me out. However I would like to get other’s opinion too.

Comment: Kinda relevant: [Stockholm Syndrome](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/StockholmSyndrome)

Comment: Not a duplicate, but related: [When does accepting an offer to stay with my current firm make sense?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/54748/when-does-accepting-an-offer-to-stay-with-my-current-firm-make-sense)

Comment: Might be relevant to add location. A lot of countries have probation periods that would justify leaving with little consequences.

Comment: "What would yours be?" I wouldn't be in this situation in the first place, so the question is not even relevant. Quite frankly, "my heart goes out to my old company" is plain nonsense. You clearly disliked the place strongly enough to quit it and get another job. Nothing much can change in 2 months that will force such a drastic change of heart. It sounds like you just want to accept their better offer from a moral high ground.

Answer (score 3):

I would not overthink the resume. If you worked for:

- Corp A from 2013 to Sep 2017
- Corp B Oct and Nov 2017
- Corp A again Dec 2017 ... 2019?

When you´ll be applying elsewhere in the future, you could just trim it to:

- Corp A 2013 to ... 2019?

Where do you want to be in 5 years? Miserable but with a great CV or Satisfied, but some minor flaws on paper? If you read the vita of some great and successful person, you´ll discover that they seldom have a straightforward path to their success but rather followed their passion including all the small and big errors that lie on the way.

Comment: "Where do you want to be in 5 years? Miserable but with a great CV or Satisfied, but some minor flaws on paper?"  - Great line.

Answer (score 1):

> Would this look bad on my resume?  what would you do if you were in my shoes?

Hard to tell for sure, but just being for 2 months in a job and then changing to another could be seen as job-hopping, possibly denoting unstable labor conditions which could be unfavorable.

It seems that you were quite a considerable amount of time in your ex company, then you changed work for 2 months and, possibly, return to the ex company after that. That may also raise some suspicions.

In some cases, 2 months may be too few time to even consider including it as "work experience". It is not a rule, but some folks prefer to include jobs you have been for at least 6 months, and consider anything less not worth mentioning (probably because the unstable behavior it may convey).

That being said, make sure that whatever made you leave your ex company last time will not be an issue this time, if not you may find yourself in the same situation again even if you got a new and interesting offer.

It could also be wise to try to stay in your current company longer if possible, as you mentioned that the cause of your discomfort (your boss, you say) is probably temporary so things could improve with time. This will also reflect positively on your job history and stability. Hope this helps and good luck with your job hunt.

Comment: Two months is still within the probation period. Which applies to employer and employee likewise. Actually, if you are unhappy in a job, leaving after two months is a lot better than leaving after a year, for everyone involved.

Comment: @gnasher729 I agree, leaving the new company isn't a problem. But at this point trying to go back to the old company probably is not advisable. That would look suspicious on the resume.

Comment: Why not? If the old company takes you back, where's the problem? The old company might be glad to take you back.

Comment: @joe Strazzere Sure, problems don’t go away, but this was about “looks suspicious on the resume”. If the old company who knows you for four years takes you back, that looks like a recommendation to me.